# onResume() called before onAttach() and onCreateView()

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

My problem is that my fragments are not yet created when onResume() is called whereas I need them to do some actions (in onResume)

When I start my app, here is what happens :

> OnCreate() -> OnStart() -> OnResume() -> getItem() -> OnAttach() ->
>   OnCreateView()

While I'm looking at the fragment's and activity's lifecycle schema, onAttach() and onCreateView() are called before onResume() and juste after onCreate()

Any idea ? Thanks

**EDIT**

I succeeded by putting my instructions in the fragment's onResume(), but I still don't understand why activity's onResume() is called before fragment's onAttach()

**EDIT 2**

When I launch my app with another device (emulator in this case), activity's onResume() is called AFTER onAttach(), this time...
I really don't get it. I'd be glad if someone could explain me :)